# I am getting an unknown file path error and I can't figure out why?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a VBA code section in Access that runs a query using inputs on a form (one input is for the query, the other is for the filename to be saved). For some reason I am getting an invalid file path error but the path is legit as I can tell. Why I am I getting the error? FileName is the desired name of the spreadsheet to be saved from the form.
This is what I get from access for the error:

[image]

```
Private Sub AllPaybacks_Click()
Dim getFolder As Object
Dim sLoc As String
Dim fileN As String

Set getFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With getFolder
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    getFolder.InitialFileName = FileName.Value
    fileN = getFolder.InitialFileName
    If .Show = True Then
        sLoc = getFolder.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End If
End With

DoCmd.OpenQuery "PaybackQ"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "PaybackQ", sLoc & fileN & ".xlsx", True
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried with other file paths? Is the file locked or do you have permissions?

Comment: @nicomp I have tried other paths and filenames. When I hard code the file name in the VBA code it works fine. This issue arose when I added the getFolder.InitialFileName = FileName.Value
fileN = getFolder.InitialFileName to try and pull the desired file name from a text box on the form.

Comment: Does it happen on the TransferSpreadsheet  statement?

Comment: Do you hard code the path copied from the error message and it works?

Comment: @nicomp Yes the error happens at the transferspreadsheet command.Also when I set fileN to a string such as "test" before the if statement it works fine. I also tried hard coding the path and got the same error. It appears the error lies with the lines getFolder.InitialFileName = FileName.Value
    fileN = getFolder.InitialFileName   My goal is to take the text in the text box on the form and use it for the file name.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the wrong syntax to solve this. In order to use the data in my text box on my form as the file name I needed to do the following.

```
Private Sub AllPaybacks_Click()
Dim getFolder As Object
Dim sLoc As String
Dim fileN As String

Set getFolder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With getFolder
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    fileN = Forms!PaybackSearchF!FileName
    If .Show = True Then
        sLoc = getFolder.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End If
End With

DoCmd.OpenQuery "PaybackQ"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, , "PaybackQ", sLoc & fileN & ".xlsx", True

End Sub
```

fileN = Forms!PaybackSearchF!FileName appropriately read in the string in the text box from my form.